# Special properties of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry

Are there any special (nontrivial) properties of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that distinguish it from any other $\mathbb{R}^n$? If there are, what are some of the important ones?

Comment: The number of convex, regular polyhedron?

Comment: I was wondering because I recently learned that for 1 dimensional ODE, oscillating solutions are not possible, while for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and above, oscillation is possible. I was wondering if there are results that hold true for $\mathbb{R}^3$ but for no other $\mathbb{R}^n$, including $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The fact that it can be embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ but not $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @AlexBecker but $\mathbb{R}^n$ can always be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but not $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$

Comment: @jshin47 I wasn't sure if you were aware of invariance of domain.

Comment: Troll: $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the only $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n=3$. On a serious note, I am also very interested in an answer.

Comment: It would be interesting to look at some results from low-dimensional topology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The unit sphere $\{x:\|x\|=1\}$ in $\mathbb R^3$ has the property that the area of each spherical slice 
   $\{x:a\le x_1\le b\}$, $-1\le a\le b\le 1$, depends only on $b-a$. In more technical terms, the pushforward of the 
   surface measure on a sphere under orthogonal projection to a line is a uniform measure on some segment. This property fails in all other dimensions.
2. Nontrivial knots (informally speaking: smooth simple closed curves that cannot be continuously deformed to a circle) exist  in $\mathbb R^3$ but not in $\mathbb R^n$ for $n\ne 3$.

Comment: For the second statement, why can't you have such a knot in an embedding of $\mathbb{R}^3$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for $n \gt 3$?

Comment: @jshin47 Then you'd be able to unknot it (deform to a circle) in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 5):

Not quite a unique property, but close:

A non-trivial vector [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product#Definition) can be defined only in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^7$.

Comment: Another factoid that distinguishes $\mathbb{R}^7$ is that [the hypersphere has a larger surface area](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersphere.html) than a hypersphere in any other $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2):

A random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}^2$ will return to the origin almost surely, but [this fails for $\mathbb{Z}^3$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyasRandomWalkConstants.html).  It is not related to the reals specifically but it is a curious difference between two dimensions and three.

Comment: Since this doesn't answer the question, don't you think it should be a comment?

Comment: @nonpop, I think it is an answer because $\mathbb{Z}^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Hmm, well I guess the question is vague enough that it could be...

Comment: This property does not distinguish $\mathbb R^3$ from $\mathbb R^n$ with $n>3$.